# To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, view, gantt-view

I have created a Gantt view for document library. Everything configured correctly. But when user add item using inline editing user gets error

> "To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()"

.
But same thing work perfectly for lists, but not working for document libraries.
Is it a known issue in SP2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot create an item in a document library without an associated file. Inline editing lets you fill in the column data, but does not have an interface for uploading a file, and thus cannot be used to create new documents in a library. This behavior is inherent to document libraries.

Every item in a document library needs to have an underlying file or folder before you can fill in the item's metadata.

Comment: How can I do it? Now I use `lib.RootFolder.Files.Add()` and then try to assotitate this file with item but get this error.